# Swift :Expected expression in list of expressions & Expected ',' separator

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase



class DataService
{
static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/)")
private var _USER_REF = Firebase(url: "\(https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/)/users")
private var _JOKE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/)/jokes")

var BASE_REF: Firebase
{
    return _BASE_REF
}

var USER_REF: Firebase
{
    return _USER_REF
}

var CURRENT_USER_REF: Firebase
{
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}

var JOKE_REF: Firebase
{
    return _JOKE_REF
}

}
```

I am getting this error 
1. Expected expression in list of expressions
2. Expected ',' separator
I tried cleaning Project but nothing happened. I am using xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Please mention on which line you are getting errors? Btw..Didn't you upgrade your Firebase to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Firebase(url: "(https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/)")  lines are wrong  "(https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/)")    these are strings not variables , 
simply change the lines to this

```
private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/")
private var _USER_REF = Firebase(url: "https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/users")
private var _JOKE_REF = Firebase(url: "https://jokes-fbb87.firebaseio.com/jokes")
```